# python чтение из файла

Tags: python, файлы

```
with open ('настройка.txt', 'r') as file:

  file_r = file.read()

  lines = file.readlines()

  print(lines)
```

выдаёт []
хотя файл не пуст

Answer (score 3):

после строки `file_r = file.read()` позиция / курсор файла находится в конце - поэтому `file.readlines()` вернет пустой список.

Воспользуйтесь либо `file.read()` либо `file.readlines()`, но не обеими функциями.

Читать одни и те же данные два раза - непозволительная трата ресурсов.

Если вам нужна вторая переменная со списком строк (в дополнение к переменной содержащей весь текст файла) - воспользуйтесь методом [str.splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
lines = file_r.splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

`file` — это поток, поэтому представьте, что вы сами ходите по файлу с курсором. После того, как вы совершили `read()`, ваш курсор находится в конце и дальше читать некуда.

Если точно нужны обе переменные — воспользуйтесь `file.seek(0)`, это переместит курсор в начало файла.